Optimizing SQL Server performance: merging budget and actuals tables after same CTE transformations and dimension joins
I have created a SQL query where I merge columns from a Budget table and columns from an Actuals table together using the same dimensions to join on customer, date and product. They need to undergo the same steps. If a product has been sold at least one time in that year by a customer than the yearmonth from 1 to 12 should be shown regardless if it has been sold or not in that particular yearmonth. This is the same for the budget.
Another requirement is that sometimes there is a budget for particular customer, product, yearmonth but no sales and it could be the other way around, or there is also both.
I created separate CTE_s, for the joins for Budget and joins for Actuals but they basically have the same steps. As I do it like that, it seems that my query is not performant at all. Now it is based on dummy data but with the actual data, I speak about less than 250.000 rows.
I know I can create indexes on my columns but I'm very sure it is possible to make this query easier but I don't have the experience.
This a dummy set of data:
DIM_CUSTOMER:
DECLARE @DIM_CUSTOMERS TABLE
                       (
                           [BusinessKey] INT, 
                           [CustomerCode] INT, 
                           [Customer] NVARCHAR(255), 
                           [Country] NVARCHAR(255)
                       )
 
INSERT INTO @DIM_CUSTOMERS
VALUES 
(10000, 1001, 'Kevin N.V.', 'Belgium'),
(10001, 1002, 'V.Z.W. Frederik', 'Belgium'),
(10002, 1003, 'Klaas S.A.', 'France'),
(10003, 1004, 'Nils N.V.', 'Belgium'),
(10004, 1005, 'Kevin N.V.', 'Belgium')
SELECT * FROM @DIM_CUSTOMERS

DIM_PRODUCTS:
DECLARE @DIM_PRODUCTS TABLE
                      (
                          [BusinessKey] INT, 
                          [Product] NVARCHAR(50), 
                          [ProductGroup] NVARCHAR(50)
                      )
 
INSERT INTO @DIM_PRODUCTS
VALUES
(9000, 'PH114', 'NXPLT'),
(9001, 'PH272', 'NXPLT'),
(9002, 'PH878', 'NXPLT'),
(9003, 'PH900', 'DSAKS')

DIM_DATES:
DECLARE @DIM_DATES TABLE
                   (
                       [BusinessKey] INT, 
                       [Year] INT, 
                       [Month] INT, 
                       [YearMonth] INT, 
                       [YearMonthText] NVARCHAR(20)
                   )

INSERT INTO @DIM_DATES
VALUES
(202201, 2022, 1, 202201, '2022.01'),
(202202, 2022, 2, 202202, '2022.02'),
(202203, 2022, 3, 202203, '2022.03'),
(202204, 2022, 4, 202204, '2022.04'),
(202205, 2022, 5, 202205, '2022.05'),
(202206, 2022, 6, 202206, '2022.06'),
(202207, 2022, 7, 202207, '2022.07'),
(202208, 2022, 8, 202208, '2022.08'),
(202209, 2022, 9, 202209, '2022.09'),
(202210, 2022, 10, 202210, '2022.10'),
(202211, 2022, 11, 202211, '2022.11'),
(202212, 2022, 12, 202212, '2022.12'),
(202301, 2023, 1, 202301, '2023.01'),
(202302, 2023, 2, 202302, '2023.02'),
(202303, 2023, 3, 202303, '2023.03'),
(202304, 2023, 4, 202304, '2023.04'),
(202305, 2023, 5, 202305, '2023.05'),
(202306, 2023, 6, 202306, '2023.06'),
(202307, 2023, 7, 202307, '2023.07'),
(202308, 2023, 8, 202308, '2023.08'),
(202309, 2023, 9, 202309, '2023.09'),
(202310, 2023, 10, 202310, '2023.10'),
(202311, 2023, 11, 202311, '2023.11'),
(202312, 2023, 12, 202312, '2023.12'),
(202401, 2024, 1, 202401, '2024.01'),
(202402, 2024, 2, 202402, '2024.02'),
(202403, 2024, 3, 202403, '2024.03'),
(202404, 2024, 4, 202404, '2024.04'),
(202405, 2024, 5, 202405, '2024.05'),
(202406, 2024, 6, 202406, '2024.06'),
(202407, 2024, 7, 202407, '2024.07'),
(202408, 2024, 8, 202408, '2024.08'),
(202409, 2024, 9, 202409, '2024.09'),
(202410, 2024, 10, 202410, '2024.10'),
(202411, 2024, 11, 202411, '2024.11'),
(202412, 2024, 12, 202412, '2024.12')

FACT_SALES:
DECLARE @FACT_SALES TABLE
                    (
                        [ID] INT, 
                        [FK_Product] INT, 
                        [FK_Customer] INT, 
                        [FK_Date] INT, 
                        [Sales] FLOAT
                    )

INSERT INTO @FACT_SALES
VALUES
(1, 9000, 10000, 202303, 90.48),
(2, 9000, 10000, 202304, 20.40),
(3, 9002, 10000, 202305, 250.85),
(4, 9002, 10000, 202303, 100.50),
(5, 9000, 10000, 202403, 38.40),
(6, 9000, 10000, 202406, 474.50),
(7, 9001, 10000, 202403, 128.60),
(8, 9001, 10000, 202404, 144.97),
(9, 9000, 10002, 202303, 199.60),
(10, 9001, 10002, 202302, 58.97),
(11, 9001, 10002, 202402, 40.88),
(12, 9001, 10000, 202203, 14.5),
(13, 9002, 10000, 202305, 50.60),
(14, 9001, 10003, 202402, 70.85),
(15, 9001, 10003, 202408, 150.45),
(16, 9000, 10003, 202304, 46.63),
(17, 9002, 10003, 202305, 10.12),
(18, 9002, 10003, 202405, 90.12),
(19, 9000, 10004, 202303, 54.98),
(20, 9000, 10004, 202304, 87.89),
(21, 9002, 10004, 202306, 77.88),
(22, 9000, 10000, 202304, 77.50)

FACT_BUDGET:
DECLARE @FACT_BUDGET TABLE
                     (
                         [ID] INT, 
                         [Product] NVARCHAR(20), 
                         [FK_CustomerCode] INT, 
                         [FK_Date] INT, 
                         [Budget] FLOAT
                     )

INSERT INTO @FACT_BUDGET
VALUES
(1, 'PH114', 1001, 202303, 50.5),
(2, 'PH114', 1002, 202403, 100.40),
(3, 'PH878', 1003, 202306, 250.85),
(4, 'PH114', 1003, 202301, 85.96)


My query attempt:
;WITH SALES_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS_YEARS_CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT dim_dates.[Year] AS [VolumesYear],
                    fact_sales.[FK_Product],
                    fact_sales.[FK_Customer]
    FROM @FACT_SALES fact_sales
    INNER JOIN @DIM_DATES dim_dates
        ON fact_sales.[FK_Date] = dim_dates.[BusinessKey]
), 
CUSTOMER_SALES_CTE AS
(
    SELECT sales_customers_products_years_cte.[FK_Customer],
           sales_customers_products_years_cte.[FK_Product],
           dim_dates.[Year],
           dim_dates.[Month],
           dim_dates.[YearMonthText],
           fact_sales.[Sales]
    FROM SALES_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS_YEARS_CTE sales_customers_products_years_cte
    INNER JOIN @DIM_DATES dim_dates
        ON sales_customers_products_years_cte.[VolumesYear] = dim_dates.[Year]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @FACT_SALES fact_sales
        ON sales_customers_products_years_cte.[FK_Customer] = fact_sales.[FK_Customer]
        AND sales_customers_products_years_cte.[FK_Product] = fact_sales.[FK_Product]
        AND dim_dates.[BusinessKey] = fact_sales.[FK_Date]
), 
ACTUALS_CTE AS
(
    SELECT dim_customers.[BusinessKey],
           dim_products.[Product],
           customer_sales_cte.[YearMonthText],
           SUM(customer_sales_cte.[Sales]) AS [Sales]
    FROM @DIM_CUSTOMERS dim_customers
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_SALES_CTE customer_sales_cte
        ON dim_customers.[BusinessKey] = customer_sales_cte.[FK_Customer]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DIM_PRODUCTS dim_products
        ON customer_sales_cte.[FK_Product] = dim_products.[BusinessKey]
    WHERE dim_products.[ProductGroup] = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY dim_customers.[BusinessKey],
             dim_products.[Product],
             customer_sales_cte.[YearMonthText],
             customer_sales_cte.[Year],
             customer_sales_cte.[Month]
), 
BUDGET_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS_YEARS_CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT dim_dates.[Year] AS [BudgetYear],
                    fact_budget.[Product],
                    fact_budget.[FK_CustomerCode]
    FROM @FACT_BUDGET fact_budget
    INNER JOIN @DIM_DATES dim_dates
        ON fact_budget.[FK_Date] = dim_dates.[BusinessKey]
), 
CUSTOMER_BUDGET_CTE AS
(
    SELECT budget_customers_products_years_cte.[FK_CustomerCode],
           budget_customers_products_years_cte.[Product],
           dim_dates.[Year],
           dim_dates.[Month],
           dim_dates.[YearMonthText],
           fact_budget.[Budget]
    FROM BUDGET_CUSTOMERS_PRODUCTS_YEARS_CTE budget_customers_products_years_cte
    INNER JOIN @DIM_DATES dim_dates
        ON budget_customers_products_years_cte.[BudgetYear] = dim_dates.[Year]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @FACT_BUDGET fact_budget
        ON budget_customers_products_years_cte.FK_CustomerCode = fact_budget.[FK_CustomerCode]
        AND budget_customers_products_years_cte.Product = fact_budget.Product
        AND dim_dates.[BusinessKey] = fact_budget.[FK_Date]
), 
BUDGET_CTE AS
(
    SELECT dim_customers.[BusinessKey],
           dim_products.[Product],
           customer_budget_cte.[YearMonthText],
           SUM(customer_budget_cte.Budget) AS [Budget]
    FROM @DIM_CUSTOMERS dim_customers
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_BUDGET_CTE customer_budget_cte
        ON dim_customers.[CustomerCode] = customer_budget_cte.[FK_CustomerCode]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Product],
                        [ProductGroup]
        FROM @DIM_PRODUCTS
    ) dim_products
            ON customer_budget_cte.[Product] = dim_products.[Product]
    WHERE dim_products.[ProductGroup] = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY dim_customers.[BusinessKey],
             dim_products.[Product],
             customer_budget_cte.[YearMonthText],
             customer_budget_cte.[Year],
             customer_budget_cte.[Month]
)
SELECT 
    customer.[BusinessKey],
    [Product],
    [YearMonthText],
    ISNULL(MIN([Budget]), 0) AS [Budget],
    ISNULL(MIN([Sales]), 0) AS [Actuals]
FROM
    @DIM_CUSTOMERS customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         [BusinessKey],
         [Product],
         [YearMonthText],
         [Budget],
         NULL AS [Sales]
     FROM 
         BUDGET_CTE budget_cte
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         [BusinessKey],
         [Product],
         [YearMonthText],
         NULL AS [Budget],
         [Sales]
     FROM 
         ACTUALS_CTE actuals_cte) a ON customer.[BusinessKey] = a.[BusinessKey]
WHERE 
    a.[Product] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    customer.[BusinessKey], [Product], [YearMonthText];

Thank you!

Does your real query really use just table variables?

Have you considered using other table-variables or temporary-tables to hold intermediate results, so you can break-up your huge CTE into something more... comprehensible?

Please focus on the first word of [mre]

Stringing that many CTEs together into one query is asking for performance issues. Consider instead using a temp table or 2 (definitely not a table variable) to materialize your results mid-way.

Distinct is also bad for performance and often indicates a sloppy query.

Aside... if you care about performance then you might want to move to temp tables instead of table variables. SQL Server's cardinality estimator uses fixed row count estimates for table variables - 1 row on 2017 and earlier, 100 rows on 2019 and later - and so execution plans are built on top of that defective assumption.

@ThomA, what I forgot to mention is that I'm using real tables instead of table variables as the latter are for demo purposes for my question. Another thing is that I want to feed a view based on this query.

@Dai What I forgot to mention is that I want to feed a view based on my SQL query and it seems based on some research that temp tables cannot be used in a view or am I wrong. Is there another alternative than using temp tables for a view other than CTE's?

@DaleK About the distinct, maybe I can use a group by if that makes a difference in the performance? About stringing CTE's, like I already told in my previous comments, and what I forgot to mention in my initial question, is that I want to feed a view based on my query and it seems that temp tables cannot be used in a view.

I doubt removing distinct will make that much of an improvement. Forgetting to mention that its for a view, pretty much invalidates the question. You can't leave out important details like that and hope for an answer. You might be able to improve things with the right indexes, which you would be able to work out from the execution plan (which you should have posted for a performance question). However I suspect you might not be able to make that query faster. Its too complex and convoluted. Sometimes you have to pre-calculate data, and store it, either via trigger or maintenance procedure.

I think you are on the right track. However, assuming that the FACT_BUDGET and FACT_SALES tables are sparsely populated relative to the customer/product/month combinations in the final report, I would suggest deferring any combining of budget/sales data with the generated date ranges as much as possible.
My suggested order of operations is:

Aggregate budget data by customer/product/month.
Aggregate sales data by customer/product/month.
Combine aggregated budget and sales data using a full outer join.
Extract a distinct combinations of customer/product/year from the combined aggregated budget and sales data.
Expand the customer/product/year combination to include all 12 months.
Left join the generated customer/product/month data with the combined
aggregated budget and sales data.

Something like:
WITH CTE_SumBudget AS (
    SELECT
        P.BusinessKey AS ProductKey,
        C.BusinessKey AS CustomerKey,
        B.FK_Date AS DateKey,
        SUM(B.Budget) AS Budget
    FROM FACT_BUDGET B
    JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.Product = B.Product
    JOIN DIM_CUSTOMERS C ON C.CustomerCode = B.FK_CustomerCode
    --WHERE P.ProductGroup = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY 
        P.BusinessKey,
        C.BusinessKey,
        B.FK_Date
),
CTE_SumSales AS (
    SELECT
        S.FK_Product AS ProductKey,
        S.FK_Customer AS CustomerKey,
        S.FK_Date AS DateKey,
        SUM(S.Sales) AS Sales
    FROM FACT_SALES S
    --JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.BusinessKey = B.FK_Product
    --WHERE P.ProductGroup = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY 
        S.FK_Product,
        S.FK_Customer,
        S.FK_Date
),
CTE_SumBudgetSales AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(SS.ProductKey, SB.ProductKey) AS ProductKey,
        COALESCE(SS.CustomerKey, SB.CustomerKey) AS CustomerKey,
        COALESCE(SS.DateKey, SB.DateKey) AS DateKey,
        SB.Budget,
        SS.Sales
    FROM CTE_SumBudget SB
    FULL OUTER JOIN CTE_SumSales SS
        ON SS.ProductKey = SB.ProductKey
        AND SS.CustomerKey = SB.CustomerKey
        AND SS.DateKey = SB.DateKey
  
),
CTE_CustomerProductYears AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        SBS.ProductKey,
        SBS.CustomerKey,
        D.Year
    FROM CTE_SumBudgetSales SBS
    JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.BusinessKey = SBS.DateKey
),
CTE_CustomerProductYearMonths AS (
    SELECT
        CPY.ProductKey,
        CPY.CustomerKey,
        D.BusinessKey AS DateKey
    FROM CTE_CustomerProductYears CPY
    JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.Year = CPY.Year
)
SELECT
    C.BusinessKey,
    P.Product,
    D.YearMonthText,
    ISNULL(SBS.Budget, 0) AS Budget,
    ISNULL(SBS.Sales, 0) AS Actuals
FROM CTE_CustomerProductYearMonths CPYM
JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.BusinessKey = CPYM.ProductKey
JOIN DIM_CUSTOMERS C ON C.BusinessKey = CPYM.CustomerKey
JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.BusinessKey = CPYM.DateKey
LEFT JOIN CTE_SumBudgetSales SBS
    ON SBS.ProductKey = CPYM.ProductKey
    AND SBS.CustomerKey = CPYM.CustomerKey
    AND SBS.DateKey = CPYM.DateKey
ORDER BY
    C.BusinessKey,
    P.Product,
    D.YearMonthText
;

For the purposes of the above query, I have replaced the table variable references with normal table references. I am assuming the source tables contain typical primary key definitions, foreign key constrains, and appropriate indexes to support the join conditions.
Partial results



BusinessKey
Product
YearMonthText
Budget
Actuals




10000
PH114
2023.01
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.02
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.03
50.5
90.48


10000
PH114
2023.04
0
97.9


10000
PH114
2023.05
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.06
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.07
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.08
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.09
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.10
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.11
0
0


10000
PH114
2023.12
0
0


10000
PH114
2024.01
0
0


10000
PH114
2024.02
0
0


10000
PH114
2024.03
0
38.4


10000
PH114
2024.04
0
0


10000
PH114
2024.05
0
0


10000
PH114
2024.06
0
474.5


10000
PH114
2024.07
0
0


...
...
...
...
...


10000
PH272
2022.03
0
14.5


...
...
...
...
...


10000
PH272
2024.03
0
128.6


10000
PH272
2024.04
0
144.97


...
...
...
...
...


10000
PH878
2023.03
0
100.5


10000
PH878
2023.04
0
0


10000
PH878
2023.05
0
301.45


...
...
...
...
...



One thing I noted when looking at the execution plans was that SQL was executing two different variants of the CTE_SumBudgetSales portion of the query - once to get the full budget and sales data, and once just to extract just the customer/product/date information. As a possible alternative that avoids this, I split and modified the query to write the CTE_SumBudgetSales to a #temp table, and then reference that table in the logic that followed.
-- Modification to the above that splits the query into two parts,
-- storing intermediate data into a temporary table

-- Aggregate budget and sales data into a temporary table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SumBudgetSales') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SumBudgetSales;

WITH CTE_SumBudget AS (
    SELECT
        P.BusinessKey AS ProductKey,
        C.BusinessKey AS CustomerKey,
        B.FK_Date AS DateKey,
        SUM(B.Budget) AS Budget
    FROM FACT_BUDGET B
    JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.Product = B.Product
    JOIN DIM_CUSTOMERS C ON C.CustomerCode = B.FK_CustomerCode
    --WHERE P.ProductGroup = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY 
        P.BusinessKey,
        C.BusinessKey,
        B.FK_Date
),
CTE_SumSales AS (
    SELECT
        S.FK_Product AS ProductKey,
        S.FK_Customer AS CustomerKey,
        S.FK_Date AS DateKey,
        SUM(S.Sales) AS Sales
    FROM FACT_SALES S
    --JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.BusinessKey = B.FK_Product
    --WHERE P.ProductGroup = 'NXPLT'
    GROUP BY 
        S.FK_Product,
        S.FK_Customer,
        S.FK_Date
),
CTE_SumBudgetSales AS (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(SS.ProductKey, SB.ProductKey) AS ProductKey,
        COALESCE(SS.CustomerKey, SB.CustomerKey) AS CustomerKey,
        COALESCE(SS.DateKey, SB.DateKey) AS DateKey,
        SB.Budget,
        SS.Sales
    FROM CTE_SumBudget SB
    FULL OUTER JOIN CTE_SumSales SS
        ON SS.ProductKey = SB.ProductKey
        AND SS.CustomerKey = SB.CustomerKey
        AND SS.DateKey = SB.DateKey
  
)
SELECT *
INTO #SumBudgetSales
FROM CTE_SumBudgetSales;

-- Index to assist with final left-join
CREATE INDEX #IX_SumBudgetSales
    ON #SumBudgetSales(ProductKey, CustomerKey, DateKey);
  
-- Now use the temp table for the final query
WITH CTE_CustomerProductYears AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        SBS.ProductKey,
        SBS.CustomerKey,
        D.Year
    FROM #SumBudgetSales SBS
    JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.BusinessKey = SBS.DateKey
),
CTE_CustomerProductYearMonths AS (
    SELECT
        CPY.ProductKey,
        CPY.CustomerKey,
        D.BusinessKey AS DateKey
    FROM CTE_CustomerProductYears CPY
    JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.Year = CPY.Year
)
SELECT
    C.BusinessKey,
    P.Product,
    D.YearMonthText,
    ISNULL(SBS.Budget, 0) AS Budget,
    ISNULL(SBS.Sales, 0) AS Actuals
FROM CTE_CustomerProductYearMonths CPYM
JOIN DIM_PRODUCTS P ON P.BusinessKey = CPYM.ProductKey
JOIN DIM_CUSTOMERS C ON C.BusinessKey = CPYM.CustomerKey
JOIN DIM_DATES D ON D.BusinessKey = CPYM.DateKey
LEFT JOIN #SumBudgetSales SBS
    ON SBS.ProductKey = CPYM.ProductKey
    AND SBS.CustomerKey = CPYM.CustomerKey
    AND SBS.DateKey = CPYM.DateKey
ORDER BY
    C.BusinessKey,
    P.Product,
    D.YearMonthText
;

DROP TABLE #SumBudgetSales;

See this db<>fiddle for a demo that includes:

Table definitions and data inserts.
The proposed query.
The modified (split) proposed query using a #temp table.
The original query, modified to use ordinary tables.
The original query, as posted using table variables

The fiddle also includes execution plans for review.
There is not much difference in the general complexity of the execution plans, perhaps a slight improvement with the proposed queries, if you count the number of table and index reference steps. (I did not perform an in-depth analysis.)
I would call the results for this small sample data set inconclusive, and recommend that you run further tests against scaled-up data sets to determine what real-world performance looks like.
One more note: Your posted query included the condition WHERE dim_products.[ProductGroup] = 'NXPLT', but none of your sample data is excluded by this condition. (There are no product 9003 references.) I left this condition commented out in my query. You can uncomment this or add other conditions as needed.

Thank you for your time to respond to my question! I will check this out more in detail but the query looks better than what I have written. As some other people already asked, why not using temp tables. I forgot to mention in my initial question that I want to feed a view based on my SQL query. I don't know if temp tables are still possible in that case?

Wrapping all this up in a view might not be a good design. As written, the above query will return data for all customers, all products, and all dates (year-months). Typically a view is intended for inclusion in other queries that often filter the results - either  implicitly with joins or explicitly with conditions like BusinessKey = 'x' or 'YearMonthText BETWEEN '2023-09' AND '2023-12'`. The problem is that SQL Server might not be able to propagate these filter conditions down into the complex view logic to efficiently limit the data being retrieved. (continued...)

(...continued) Instead, the server may end up calculating the entire result set whenever the view is referenced, only to throw most of the data away if the outer query is only asking for a single month's worth of data for a single customer.  It might be better to review your use cases and design one or more parameterized stored procedures that carefully apply the limiting parameters early in the queries, so that only the minimum required data is retrieved.
